# Adding padding between the fringe and the text

Tags: fringe, fringe-mode, margins

How can I add padding between the right side of the fringe and the left side of my code?

I have tried using `(set-window-margins nil 1)` but the margin is on the left side of the fringe. I'd like to have it on the right side, for more reading clarity (see capture below)

[image: Illustration of the lack of padding]

EDIT : I forgot to mention that I'm using Emacs in GUI mode on Windows

Comment: How about setting the following buffer-local variables with a default of your liking:  `(setq-default left-fringe-width  30) (setq-default right-fringe-width  0)`  To change the color of the fringe, use something like:  `(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "black")`  To make the fringe invisible, match the color of the fringe to the `default` background face.

Comment: @lawlist I actually use the fringe for some bitmaps such as hideshow symbols or git stuff... But you're right, I could make make the fringe "invisible" and still have the symbols in there. That will be my solution if the padding thing isn't possible.

Comment: I have not seen any adjustment for padding using the built-in native line numbers, however, the old-style Lisp line numbering is easy to add padding and there are several old threads on stackoverflow (perhaps here too) describing how to do that.